# Scale up MouseOver on button for WPF Style

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently working on a C# WPF project and I am trying to make my custom style buttons.

What I want to have to happen, is when the mouse hovers over the button, it slightly increases in size as an animation, then when the mouse leaves the button, the animation decreases the size of the button to the original size.

Below is my ControlTemplate that I've created for my button. No errors are thrown but nothing happens either.

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid Name="ButtonGrid">
                            <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"></ContentPresenter>
                            </Border>

                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Blue"/>
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                        To="0.95"  Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                                        To="0.95" Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                        To="1.08"  Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                                        To="1.08" Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="ButtonGrid" Value="0.25"/>
                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have couple of problems with your code:

1) You are trying to animate `Rectangle.RenderTransform` properties and there is no Rectangle in your ControlTemplate. `RenderTransform` is a dependency property on UIElement. So, you should remove `Rectangle`

2) Also, There is no `RenderTransform` applied to your Grid.

3) After fixing above two items, if you try you get continuous animation (Button expanding/shrinking in size), to fix this set `Background` property Grid to Transparent, so that Grid participates in hit testing and respond to Mouse overs.

Update your style XAML to the following and it will work:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Grid Name="ButtonGrid" Background="Transparent">
                 <Border
                    x:Name="border"
                    BorderBrush="White"
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    CornerRadius="8">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextElement.FontWeight="Bold">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                 </Border>
                 <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform />
                 </Grid.RenderTransform>
              </Grid>
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                       <BeginStoryboard>
                          <Storyboard>
                             <DoubleAnimation
                                Duration="0:0:0.05"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                To="0.95"/>
                             <DoubleAnimation
                                Duration="0:0:0.05"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                To="0.95"/>
                          </Storyboard>
                       </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                       <BeginStoryboard>
                          <Storyboard>
                             <DoubleAnimation
                                Duration="0:0:0.05"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                To="1.08"/>
                             <DoubleAnimation
                                Duration="0:0:0.05"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                To="1.08"/>
                          </Storyboard>
                       </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                 </Trigger>
                 <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="ButtonGrid" Property="Opacity" Value="0.25"/>
                 </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Another thing, instead of using `Trigger.EnterActions` and `Trigger.ExitActions`, you could use VisualStateManager to achieve the same result. Using VisualStateManager is much more easier than Trigger.EnterActions and ExitActions.

Below is the code with VisualStateManager used to do the animations:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
     <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Grid Name="ButtonGrid" Background="Transparent">
                 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                       <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                          <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.05" To="MouseOver"/>
                          <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.05" To="Normal"/>
                       </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                       <VisualStateGroup.States>
                          <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                          <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                             <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                   To="0.95"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonGrid"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                   To="0.95"/>
                             </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                       </VisualStateGroup.States>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                 </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                 <Border
                    x:Name="border"
                    BorderBrush="White"
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    CornerRadius="8">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextElement.FontWeight="Bold">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                 </Border>
                 <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                 </Grid.RenderTransform>
              </Grid>
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                 </Trigger>
                 <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="ButtonGrid" Property="Opacity" Value="0.25"/>
                 </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
           </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
  </Style>
```